# Having error in restoring a mdf file for a delete database table

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

My subordinate mistakenly deleted all the record in our database table using delete statement without a where clause No previous backup was taken. Now i want restore from mdf file.
But i keep getting this error:

```
An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. 
  (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
```

---

```
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

 Cannot open backup device 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL 
Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER      \MSSQL\DATA\Mydabasename.mdf'. 
Operating system error  32(The process cannot access the file   
because it is being used by another process.).
RESTORE HEADERONLY is terminating abnormally. 
(Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 3201)
```

Comment: do you mean `ldf` file rather?

Comment: @Rahul that is correct:SQL Server Database Transaction Log File (.ldf)

Comment: error says that "file is being used by other programe" .- Ensure no anti-virus or anti-spyware tool is installed.
- Ensure the SQLagent has relevant privileges to access the file.
- Ensure the path & filename mentioned correctly.